fzf.vim :Changes command raises errors
I have installed fzf and fzf. in Vim  on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine. So far all the fzf.vim commands are working fine except the :Changes command. Every time I enter this command a long list(literally pages) of error messages  starting by this one:

Error detected while processing function fzf#vim#changes[9]..11[1]..81_format_change:
E684: List index out of range:  0
...
are triggered, I have to page till the end, just after that the error messages disappear and  popup window of  changes command  shows up with.

I installed  both the plugin and the search tool following  the instructions of respective  README pages
I'm using vim9.0 "huge version" compiled with Python(3.10.12), Perl(5), Lua, Cscope and Ruby(3.3.0) and GUI support
Any help or tips to pinpoint the possible error causes and solve the solve the problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !
Obs1: I'm new to programming, Linux, and Vim world.
Obs2: English is not my native language, so I apologize for the possible mistake and typos.
Execute the :Changes command and expected to list  a popup window displaying all the changes perform in the opened buffers.

Use the plugin's issue tracker.

I have found the fix, but thanks anyway. @romainl

For anyone with the same I got the fix from fzf.vim author here the link:    github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/commit
